# MOVING Files and place them into folders accordingly to text file

Tags: linux

I need to move files from ORIGIN and place them to DESTINATION accordingly to the  information contained in text file "toto.txt"

I do NOT know how to code the part which says:
place these files accordingly with the information contained in toto.txt which states 
the sub-folder structure on DESTINATION  folder"
toto.txt conatins the folder structure of ORIGIN and the files must be moved accordingly to DESTINATION but with the original folder structure location.

```
# My working Paths 
    MY_DIR1="/media/nss/MBVOL1/TEST/ORIGIN"
    MY_DIR2="/media/nss/MBVOL1/TEST/DESTINATION"


# Flag files older than 1 day and list their name\full path to “TOTO” text file
        echo "REPORT Created"
    cd $MY_DIR1 &&  find . -mindepth 0 -maxdepth 40 -mtime +1 -type f > toto.txt
    cp $MY_DIR1/toto.txt /$MY_DIR2


# Flag files older than 1 day then MOVE file to “DESTINATION” Folder
    echo "FILES Moved"
    find $MY_DIR1 -mindepth 0 -maxdepth 400 -type f -mtime +14 -exec mv '{}'  $MY_DIR2 \;
```

Comment: What is the purpose of `toto.txt`? It looks like it's the same files as the second `find` processes.

Comment: toto.txt contains filenames and puth path i.e. Folders and subfolders where the file is located.

Comment: `toto.txt` contains the output of the first `find` command. But the second `find` command results in the same files, doesn't it? So why do you need the file?

Comment: I need to move files older than x days from ORIGIN to DESTINATION.

Comment: I need to move some files from ORIGIN to DESTINATION.
I need to duplicate the folder structure (containing these files) from ORIGIN to DESTINATION
Finally, I need to move these files into their respective folders on DESTINATION.
toto.txt lists these  files\path
Example: 
ORIGIN/MB0/CV/A1.doc
ORIGIN/MB0/MB1/CV/A2.doc
A1.doc & A2.doc need to be moved from ORIGIN to DESTINATION with the same folder structure
DESTINATION/MB0/CV/A1.doc
DESTINATION/MB0/MB1/CV/A2.doc
So, how I use the path folder strcuture contained in  toto.txt to perform this task?

Comment: Please add updates to your question to the question itself, but squezzing them into comments, which makes the overall info scattered and difficult to read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
cd "$MY_DIR1"
# Duplicate directory structure
find . -type d -exec mkdir -p "$MY_DIR2"/{} \;
# move files older than 1 day
find . -type f -mtime +1 -exec mv {} "$MY_DIR2"/{} \;
```

You can combine them into one command:

```
find . -type d -exec mkdir -p "$MY_DIR2"/{} \; -o -type f -mtime +1 -exec mv {} "$MY_DIR2"/{} \;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use something like this...

```
cat ${MY_DIR2}/toto.txt | while read FILE ; do
    mv -v "${MY_DIR1}/${FILE}" "${MY_DIR2}"
done
```

Comment: Sure, but this was primarily a simple illustration of the logic required.